Non expiry Firebase staging
I'm a front-end dev, typically programming in Svelte. I'm new to Firebase and to back-end stuff in general, and I'm trying to use Firebase as I consider it a friendly way to integrate a back end into my project, which is a Chrome extension
Recently I've been trying to tackle the issue of setting up a staging environment. However, firebase hosting:channel:deploy staging isn't a great solution because the generated URL is short-lived, yet I need to put the URL hardcoded in the extension and distribute it to test users
Note that I'm not looking to set the project up with GitHub Actions, least not yet
Following Firebase environments and emulators, I tried to create a new project with the same name as my production one, suffixed wtih "Staging"
This surely complicates the development, such as setting up the local environment, but at least the deployment URL stays constant

Eventually, I figured out a workaround
Prerequisites
Have firebase-tools installed
Next

Set up multiple sites

Create a directory for Firebase, run firebase init (or firebase init hosting)


firebase target:apply hosting staging SITE_NAME_STAGING
firebase target:apply hosting production SITE_NAME_PRODUCTION


firebase/firebase.json
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "staging",
      "public": "svelte-project/build/staging",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "production",
      "public": "svelte-project/build/prod",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


svelte-project/svelte.config.js
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
    pages: "build/" + (process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.includes(`"--mode" "staging"`) ? "staging" : "prod"),
    fallback: "index.html"
  })
 }
};

export default config;


svelte-project/package.json

In my specific use case, I wanted to populate environment variables from the extension project, and so I used the --env-file flag
{
   "config": {
     "vitePath": "node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.12/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "vite:dev": "node --env-file=../../extension/.env.local %npm_package_config_vitePath%",
     "vite:test": "node --env-file=../../extension/.env.test %npm_package_config_vitePath%",
     "vite:build": "node --env-file=../../extension/.env.production %npm_package_config_vitePath%",
     "svelte-project:dev": "pnpm vite:dev dev",
     "svelte-project:build": "pnpm vite:build build",
     "svelte-project:build-staging": "pnpm svelte-project:build --mode staging"
   }
}


If you don't have this requirement, you can simplify it to
{
   "scripts": {
     "svelte-project:dev": "vite",
     "svelte-project:build": "vite build",
     "svelte-project:build-staging": "vite build --mode staging"
   }
}



Then you run svelte-project:build/svelte-project:build-staging

firebase/package.json (optional)
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy:staging": "firebase deploy --only hosting:staging",
    "deploy:production": "firebase deploy --only hosting:production",
    "build:deploy:staging": "cmd /V /C \"set root=%cd% && cd svelte-project && pnpm svelte-project:build-staging && cd !root! && pnpm deploy:staging\"",
    "build:deploy:production": "cmd /V /C \"set root=%cd% && cd svelte-project && pnpm svelte-project:build && cd !root! && pnpm deploy:production\""
  }
}



